# text-wrap: none and text-overflow:ellipses both being ignored

Tags: css

I want my text to be truncated if its too large to fit on a single line, however even though I've added text-wrap:none and text-overflow:ellipses its spilling onto more than one line and not being truncated.

```
<snip>

<ul>
<li>
<img = ...>
<div id = "track_title">text</div>
</li>
</ul>

ul {
    position:absolute:
    list-style: none;
    top:20px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

li {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("track_row_unselected.png");
    display: block;
    height: 80px;
}
#track_title {
    position:absolute;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    top: 5px;   
    left: 80px;
    width: 180px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-wrap:none;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`text-wrap`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-wrap.asp) is not supported in any major browser. Try using `white-space: nowrap;`. You also need to add `overflow: hidden;`. [Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gjvVx/1/).